# Windows 7, network transmit (send) not working

Tags: windows-7, networking

My Win 7 computer has been working fine for 2 years without a problem, but nowadays, I can't transmit big data on LAN/Internet.

I can:

- Ping anything
- Browse Internet, download files at full speed
- Send emails with very small attachments.
- Testing download speed on Speedtest.net, measure stable full speed.

I can't:

- Test the upload speed on Speedtest.net. Upload stuck..
- Save/send email messages with big (>128k) attachments, independent from email provider or email box.

***This is not a Hardware/Cable/Card or other network devices problem!*** When I boot from a Linux Live CD, without ANY hardware change, all data sending, testing works correctly, at full speed.

I have tried already in Win 7:

- Disable Windows/3rd party firewall completely
- Reset IP stack parameters (netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt)
- Computer restore
- Reinstall LAN driver

When I inspect the packets in Wireshark in Windows, I see lots of (maybe 60% of sent packets) "TCP Retransmission". Sometimes receive "TCP Dup Ack" or "TCP Out-of-Order".

Linux doesn't do this.

Comment: Please describe what exactly happens. Do connections drop? Or do uploads simply appear to be stuck? Or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: On a note related to what Daniel asked. Is there a file you try to download and it gets stuck?  Suppose you ping the server with the file.. do they all get there or do some packets get lost and does ping then give any particular message?  How about tracert to the servers

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's the MTU size set in Windows. I saw lots of TCP retransmissiosn and TCP dup ack.. (don't recall TCP out-of-oder) but I saw those when my router had an MTU of 1500 and they went when I gave it an MTU of 1400 at the advice of my router manufacturer. You could call your router manufacturer and ISP and see if they have any advice (even though/'if' it is a windows issue)

I know this isn't your router that is the issue, but Windows also has an MTU setting.

This may not work, but it is worth trying to change it in Windows.

http://www.richard-slater.co.uk/archives/2009/10/23/change-your-mtu-under-vista-windows-7-or-windows-8/

`C:\>netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces`

```
MTU         MediaSenseState  Bytes In    Bytes Out  Interface
----------  ---------------  ---------   ---------  -------------
4294967295  1                0           13487914   Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
1500        1                3734493902  282497358  Local Area Connection
```

Look for Local Area Connection and/or Wireless Area Connection in the above,   you'll be changing the MTU to or nearer to 1400.

Now try sending smaller packets until they work. Start from 1472 (that's 1500-28)
    C:>ping www.cantreachthissite.com -f -l 1472

I haven't tried that with pinging, i'll quote the author of the page here

> The host name should be a site you can not reach, -f marks the packet
>   as one that should not be fragmented the -l 1472 sets the size of the
>   packet (1472 = Ethernet Default MTU – Packet Header, where the
>   Ethernet Default MTU is 1500 and the Packet Header is 28 bytes)
>
> If the packet can’t be sent because it would need to be fragmented you
>   will get something similar to this:
>
> Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set. Keep trying lower packet
>   sizes by 10 (i.e. -l 1460, 1450, 1440, etc.) until you get a
>   successful ping request. Raise your packet sizes by one until you get
>   a “Packet needs to be fragmented but DF set.”. The last successful
>   value plus 28 will be your MTU value.
>
> In my case a packet size of 1430 succeeds but 1431 fails, so 1430 + 28
>   = 1458.

Step 3: Set your MTU

Now you have identified the interface you need to change and the ideal MTU for you, now it is time to make the change. Again from an elevated Command Prompt type the following replacing my MTU of 1458 with your own value:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=1458 store=persistent
```

Or if you are using a Wireless connection:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Wireless Network Connection" mtu=1458 store=persistent
```

^^ The above may not fix it for you, but it's just something worth trying.

Comment: Than you barlop! I tried, and not working me.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution:

On the Network Adapter properties "Energy Efficient Ethernet" set from Enabled to Disabled.

After (only) this setting speedtest.net upload and all other upload works at 100%.